# Wordpress 4.8.2 redirects back after install and asks to delete/change config

Tags: updates

I installed the newest version of wordpress today, as always (I have 20+ installations).

But with the newest version if I want to access the index site of wordpress I see this:

> The file 'wp-config.php' already exists. If you need to reset any of the configuration items in this file, please delete it first. You may try installing now.

I have no clue what I did wrong, I have a config, a DB, valid username etc. Also the installation was successful and without any errors.

Comment: This happens when WordPress cannot find any tables associated with your chosen DB. Have you checked to confirm that the tables exists?

Comment: It was a cache issue

Answer (score 0):

from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686663/error-the-file-wp-config-php-already-exists

> Is just a browser cache.
>
> On first URL load, you are redirected from domain.ext to
>   domain.ext/wp-admin/setup-config.php
>
> If you are on Chrome, just open the developers console, go to
>   "Network" tab. Reload the page and right click anywhere in the
>   console, and hit "Clear browser cache".
>
> Now refresh again and you will see your website

Answer (score -1):

o get rid of this problem just clear your browser’s cookies & cache data. Restart the browser & browse your site. The error message will no more be shown.

To clear cookies & cache data press the keyboard shortcut  shift+Ctrl+delete (for Chrome, Mozilla, Microsoft Edge) and delete the data.

If you want to clear these mannualy, follow the steps below.

For chrome browser:

```
1.On your browser toolbar, click More …
```

2. Point to More tools, and then click on “Clear browsing data”.
    3.In the “Clear browsing data” box, click the checkboxes for Cookies and other site and plug-in data and Cached images and files .
    4.Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete. Choose beginning of time to delete everything.
   5. Click Clear browsing data.

For firefox

```
1.Click the menu button (represented by three horizontal bars in the upper right corner).
```

2. Choose History, and then Clear Recent History.
   3. Set Time range to clear to Everything .
   4. Click on the arrow next to Details to expand the list of history items.
    5.Select Cookies and Cache; make sure that other items you want to keep are not selected.
    6.Click Clear Now .
   7. Exit and re-launch the browser.

Comment: That doesn't even remotely answer the question.